# SQL query for longest streak with a specific condition

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that looks like this: (There is not a record for every day and not for every field_name)

| date | field_name | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | coffee_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | coffee_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | tea_available | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | coffee_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | tea_available | 0 |
| 2021-01-06 | coffee_available | 0 |
| 2021-01-07 | coffee_available | 0 |
| 2021-01-08 | coffee_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-08 | tea_available | 1 |

I want to query the database for specific conditions, eg. the longest streak of days with coffee available or the longest streak of days with no tea available. So the result should be a single number or - even better - the longest streaks with start or end date.

I looked at the other streak questions, but I couldn't figure out how to change it so it fits my problem. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following approach which uses `ROW_NUMBER` to determine groups of sequential dates for specific conditions and `DATEDIFF` to determine the streak of days and that days within each streak differ only by 1. `COUNT` with an adjustment of 1 may also be used to determine the streak as denoted below. I included an overall query and additional queries specific to the scenario questions shared in the question.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    MIN(`DATE`),
    MAX(`DATE`),
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) AS day_streak_method_1,
    COUNT(1) - 1 AS day_streak_method_2,
    t1.field_name,
    t1.field_value 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(`DATE`, LAG(`DATE`, 1, `DATE`) OVER (PARTITION BY gnum 
        ORDER BY
            `DATE`)) AS day_diff,
            t.* 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    *,
                    (
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `field_name` 
                    ORDER BY
                        `DATE`, `field_name`) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `field_name`, `field_value` 
                    ORDER BY
                        `DATE`, `field_name`)
                    )
                    AS gnum 
                FROM
                    conditions
            )
            t
    )
    t1 
WHERE
    day_diff < 2 
GROUP BY
    gnum,
    field_name,
    field_value;
```

| MIN(`DATE`) | MAX(`DATE`) | day_streak_method_1 | day_streak_method_2 | field_name | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 | coffee_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | tea_available | 0 |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | coffee_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | tea_available | 1 |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | coffee_available | 0 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 'The longest streak of days with coffee available' as `Question 1`;
```

| Question 1 |
| --- |
| The longest streak of days with coffee available |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT
    MIN(`DATE`),
    MAX(`DATE`),
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) AS day_streak_method_1
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(`DATE`, LAG(`DATE`, 1, `DATE`) OVER (PARTITION BY gnum 
        ORDER BY
            `DATE`)) AS day_diff,
            t.* 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    *,
                    (
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `field_name` 
                    ORDER BY
                        `DATE`, `field_name`) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `field_name`, `field_value` 
                    ORDER BY
                        `DATE`, `field_name`)
                    )
                    AS gnum 
                FROM
                    conditions
                WHERE 
                    field_name='coffee_available' AND
                    field_value=1
            )
            t
    )
    t1 
WHERE
    day_diff < 2 
GROUP BY
    gnum,
    field_name,
    field_value
ORDER BY 
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

| MIN(`DATE`) | MAX(`DATE`) | day_streak_method_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 |

---

**Query #4**

```
SELECT 'The longest streak of days with no tea available' as `Question 2`;
```

| Question 2 |
| --- |
| The longest streak of days with no tea available |

---

**Query #5**

```
SELECT
    MIN(`DATE`),
    MAX(`DATE`),
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) AS day_streak_method_1
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(`DATE`, LAG(`DATE`, 1, `DATE`) OVER (PARTITION BY gnum 
        ORDER BY
            `DATE`)) AS day_diff,
            t.* 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    *,
                    (
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `field_name` 
                    ORDER BY
                        `DATE`, `field_name`) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `field_name`, `field_value` 
                    ORDER BY
                        `DATE`, `field_name`)
                    )
                    AS gnum 
                FROM
                    conditions
                WHERE 
                    field_name='tea_available' AND
                    field_value=0
            )
            t
    )
    t1 
WHERE
    day_diff < 2 
GROUP BY
    gnum,
    field_name,
    field_value
ORDER BY 
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

| MIN(`DATE`) | MAX(`DATE`) | day_streak_method_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5KEJv7Bi2JBrpkCQ7FvaWD/0)

**Edit 1**

Used less subqueries with the assistance of a case expression. *Apply additional filters in where clause where needed.*

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(`DATE`),
    MAX(`DATE`),
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) AS day_streak_method_1,
    field_name,
    field_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(
                    `date`,
                    LAG(`date`,1,`date`) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY `field_name`, `field_value`
                        ORDER BY `date`
                    )
                ) < 2 THEN (
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY `field_name` 
                        ORDER BY `date`, `field_name`
                    ) - 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY `field_name`, `field_value` 
                        ORDER BY `date`, `field_name`
                    )
                )
            ELSE NULL
        END as gnum
    FROM 
        conditions
) t
WHERE 
    gnum IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    gnum, field_name, field_value
```

*Using older versions of mysql*

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(`DATE`),
    MAX(`DATE`),
    DATEDIFF(MAX(`DATE`), MIN(`DATE`)) AS day_streak,
    field_name,
    field_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        @seq1:=IF(@seq1_prev = `field_name`,@seq1+1,1),
        @seq2:=IF(@seq2_prev = CONCAT(`field_name`, `field_value`),@seq2+1,1),
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(
                    `date`,
                     IF(
                         @seq2_prev=CONCAT(`field_name`, `field_value`),
                         @date_prev,
                         `date`
                     )
                ) < 2 THEN @seq1 - @seq2
                
            ELSE NULL
        END as gnum,
        
        @seq1_prev:=`field_name`,
        @seq2_prev:=CONCAT(`field_name`, `field_value`),
        @date_prev:=`date`
    FROM 
        conditions
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            @seq1:=0,
            @seq1_prev:=NULL,
            @seq2:=0,
            @seq2_prev:=NULL,
            @date_prev:=NULL
    ) as vars
    ORDER BY `date`, `field_name`
) t
GROUP BY 
    gnum, field_name, field_value
```

[View working demo on db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5KEJv7Bi2JBrpkCQ7FvaWD/4)

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Hi! Thank, that looks great - and it works great in the db fiddle. In my MariaDB 10.4 installation I get a syntax error near  `DATE`) OVER (PARTITION BY gnum ORDER BY `DATE`)) AS ...' Maybe this is because of my version?

Comment: @compareil Thanks for sharing the db version. MariaDB doesn't support a default value as the 3rd parameter for it's [lag function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lag/). Once omitted the shared code works, see working [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4b9e364c05ae2f5002bcfdc4264ec3a3) with modifications. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! It generally works, but all missing records are counted as 0. Eg. when there is no records for "coffee_available" for 100 days, these days count for the 0 streak.

Comment: @compareil Does this modification that removes the `daydiff < 2` comparison to facilitate such gaps work for you. See demo [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4a48d1a852048235f43b3668c57a7499)